# What is the usage of DND Operations?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am new to SWT DND, and have read this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDragAndDrop/article.html). But I'm still confused as to the usage of **DND Operations**(e.g., `DND.DROP_COPY`, `DND.DROP_MOVE`, `DND.DROP_LINK`, etc.).

1.
`DragSource` and `DropTarget` are essentially `Widget`s, and DND Operations will be passed as the `style` parameter in the constructor method. But unlike the SWT style in `Control` that the OS handles the style to adjust the appearance of `Control`, DND operation is more like a protocol, the OS will **NOT** directly realize the effect of drag and drop according to different DND operations, the actual effect is realized by the user, for example, the specific operation is `DND.DROP_MOVE`, then the user will delete the data of `DragSource` in the method `DragSourceListener.dragFinished(DragSourceEvent)` and handle the data copy on `DropTarget` in the method `DropTargetListener.drop(DropTargetEvent)`.

The above is my understanding, don't know if it is correct or not.

2.
How to trigger a specified DND operation? As shown in the example in this [section](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDragAndDrop/article.html#using-drag-and-drop-in-swt),
if I drag the `Label` without any modifier keys, the `event.detail` is always `DND.DROP_DEFAULT` in the method `DropTargetListener.dragEnter(DropTargetEvent)`, and if I drag the `Label` and press any modifier key, the `event.detail` is always `DND.DROP_MOVE`. Can I trigger the `DND.DROP_COPY` operation **directly** ?

If the code is changed to:

```java
// DND.DROP_LINK is newly added.
int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_LINK;
DragSource source = new DragSource(dragLabel, operations);
```

And how to trigger the `DND.DROP_LINK` operation ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: Mostly. The event detail should **not** be DND.DROP_MOVE on just **any** modifier, it's supposed to reflect what the windowing system uses, whether that's defined to be one of Ctrl, Cmd, Shift, or Alt. Similarly, it's a different modifier that should trigger a DND.DRP_LINK detail, and another for DND.DROP_COPY itself.  Have you come across the original articles, https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html and https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html?

Comment: There are also a couple of SWT snippets for drag and drop you might have a look at: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#dnd